# java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException on changing file in war

Tags: java

I am stuck with getting `java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException` while changing **context.xml** in my war.

Method to do that:

```
public static void replaceFileInZip(final File zipArchive, final String externalFilePath, final String zipFilePath) {
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
    env.put("create", "true");
    Path path = Paths.get(zipArchive.getPath());
    URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + path.toUri());
    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
        Path externalContext = Paths.get(externalFilePath);
        Path pathContextInArchive = fs.getPath(zipFilePath);
        Files.copy(externalContext, pathContextInArchive, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I use **StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING** and it goes OK 99 of 100. Nevertheless, sometimes I am getting exception:

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: D:\temp\Tomcat\webapps\zipfstmp8401293639854380654.tmp -> D:\temp\Tomcat\webapps\mywar.war
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.sync(ZipFileSystem.java:1297)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.close(ZipFileSystem.java:277)
at com.hryhorii.installer.controllers.service.ZipService.replaceFileInZip(ZipService.java:170)
at com.hryhorii.installer.controllers.flow.AbstractFlow.replaceContextInWar(AbstractFlow.java:120)
at com.hryhorii.installer.controllers.flow.AbstractFlow.copyApp(AbstractFlow.java:97)
at com.hryhorii.installer.controllers.flow.InstallFlow.process(InstallFlow.java:20)
at com.hryhorii.installer.controllers.ui.InstallPageController$4$1.call(InstallPageController.java:254)
at com.hryhorii.installer.controllers.ui.InstallPageController$4$1.call(InstallPageController.java:247)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$null$492(Service.java:725)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$executeTask$493(Service.java:724)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As I understand, tmp file is created when files are getting zipped, so it looks like this tmp file has to be deleted. Moreover, I could not debug this problem as it does not happen when I run this method in `while(true)` loop.

**EDIT:**

It looks like context file is replaced correctly each time. Problem could appear when changed war is trying to replace old one.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue.  It doesn't happen all the time in my code.  Maybe 2-3 times out of 10.  I'm doing a move instead of a copy, but think I'm seeing it in both cases.  I'll let you know if I make any progress

Comment: @PCalouche thank you, would be great for community